# Is there already a way to let the user choose a folder on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, directory, filesystems, google-chrome-app

I have been trying to use this Chrome code with the chooseEntry type as 'openDirectory' but I think it's not implemented yet, so I was wondering if there is already some other way to do it.

manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
    "notifications",
    {"fileSystem": ["write", "directory"]} 
],
```

Javascript:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type:'openDirectory'},function(userDirEntry){
    /*fill with files*/
});
```

This is what I get:

```
> Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property 'type': Value must be one of: [openFile, openWritableFile, saveFile].
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using it incorrectly, the manifest should look like this:

```
{"fileSystem": ["write", "directory"]},

"permissions": [
    "notifications",
    {"fileSystem": ["write", "directory"]} 
  ],
```

you can either remove value "write" or not.

and the javascript should be:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({ type: 'openDirectory'}, callback);
```

And finally in order to use the openDirectory you will need to have Chrome v31 at least installed in the computer.

Comment: ok, thank you i was trying to do "permissions": {"fileSystem": ["write", "directory"]}, which was giving me an error and doesnt work yet anyway that's why I left it like this. Thank you very much.